# Formula inside conditional sum (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, vba, macros

I have a VBA function, that check cells and returns an integer. (for example CheckThis(A5) => 23 )

How can i do something like this:

`=SUMIF(A1:E1,Checkthis(N) = 23)`

I tried various possible methods but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:E1,--(Checkthis(A1:E1)=23))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the first way, still check only one cell (A5) , i want to function check every A1:E1 cell and sum-up "Checkthis(N)=23" ones.

Comment: @AB2 see edit..

Comment: Sorry to butt in, Scott.  What will Excel do with the => symbol?  I thought OP used it as a right arrow, i.e. to imply "returns".

Comment: @Bandersnatch yup I just copied and pasted.  Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Oh good, I thought this was another one of your answers that uses stuff I don't know about.  :-)

Comment: I always appreciate the learning experience, though.  One more intrusion - for this to work, does OP's UDF need to be able to return an array, or will Excel iterate through it somehow?

Comment: My experience is that it will iterate since it is inside the SUMPRODUCT.  @Bandersnatch  But without the actual code it is hard to know.  But since the OP's example uses one cell, it should iterate.